# Hide some public properties in ServiceStack service Request and Response DTO's

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am building some services using [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net), I have a following service

```
public class FooRequest: IReturn<FooResponse>
    {
        public int FooID { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string SortColumnName { get; set; }
    }
public class FooResponse 
{
    private List<Payment> payments;
    public FooResponse()
    {
        payments= new List<Payment>();
    }
    public List<Payment> Payments
    {
        get { return payments; }
        set { payments = value; }
    }
}

public class Payment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }  // Amount is formatted string based on the user language          
    public decimal PaymentAmount{ get; set; } // this is Alias for Amount
}
```

From above FooResponse, I don't want to show PaymentAmount in `response/metadata`.

If we make it as normal variable instead of property, it won't be visible in metadata. but that should be a property for other requirement.

Is it possible in `ServiceStack` to restrict some properties in response DTO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`IgnoreDataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on the `PaymentAmount` property. Last time I checked ServiceStack was using and complying to the default .NET serialization attributes.

Comment: @irvgk: Do you have a reference to assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.dll?

Comment: @irvk: What framework version are you on? Also, are you building with Mono? Anyway, make sure the project has a reference to that assembly.

Comment: @irvgk: Add a reference explicitly. There may be some other assembly which implements stuff in namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization`, which is why you can import this namespace in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.. Working fine.. Yes.. Its all about creating reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`